# Do I need to initobj/assign null to out arguments before ldloca and call?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, il

As I see C# compiler and `Reflection.Emit` always emits `.locals init` for both value and reference type variables (even if they are later unconditionally initialized). So they can be passed as an out argument:

```
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] object x)
    L_0000: ldloca.s x
    L_0002: call void Program::MethodWithOut(object&)
    L_0007: ret
```

Are there any cases where `.locals` is used without `init` so before emitting call/callvirt I need to ensure the variable is initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that `init` is *always* required to make the code verifiable. From §III.1.8.1.1 *Verification algorithm* of [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

> Furthermore, verifiable methods shall have the localsinit bit set […]. If this bit is not set, then a CLI might throw a 
>   Verification
>    exception at any point where a local variable is accessed, and where the assembly 
>   containing that method has not been granted 
>   `SecurityPermission.SkipVerification`.

Answer (score -1):

When your are passing parameters by `ref` you need to initialize them before passing.
When you are passing parameters by `out` they must be initialized inside the called method.

Comment: Yes, I know C#. I'm asking about IL assembly rules.

Comment: I'm sorry for being confusing, see the updated question.